# React Native: "Auto" width for text node

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox

I have a text element inside a view:

`<View><Text>hello world foo bar</Text></View>`

as part of a flex grid.

I want this view to have an auto width based on the content i.e. length of the text.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can achieve this if element will have [`alignSelf` property](https://reactnative.dev/docs/layout-props#alignself), like:

```
alignSelf: 'flex-start'
```

or

```
alignSelf: 'center'
```

Comment: This does not work for me for an absolutely positioned Text node. Does anybody know how?

Comment: @OwenMasback did you ever find a solution? I have the same issue on an absolute positioned text node.

Comment: Both links in this answer are broken =(

Answer (score 0):

you can always set `minWidth: some width` and then align it to the center