# How to wrap text in react native inside a ListView?

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to make simple messaging bubbles like this:

[Desired outcome Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrTUK.png)

however, I can't figure out how to make the red background wrap the text only. I keep gutting this:

[Code output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDGON.png)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container, Header, Content, Button, Left, Icon, Body, Title, Right } from 'native-base';
import { View, StyleSheet, TextInput, ScrollView, ListView, Text } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
    this.state = {text: '', dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(['hi', 'My Name is adam']),};
  }

  render() { 
    return (
      <Container style={styles.container}>
        <ListView
          dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
          style={styles.list}
          renderRow={(rowData) => 
              <Text style={styles.senderMessageText}>
                {rowData}
              </Text>
            }
        />
      </Container>
    );
  }
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container:{
    backgroundColor: 'green'
  },
  list:{
    backgroundColor:'blue'
  },
  senderMessageText: {
    backgroundColor:'red',
    padding: 8,
    marginTop: 10
  }
});
```

I have tried everything.. Please help

Comment: Use `FlatList` instead of `ListView`. `ListView` is deprecated & `FlatList` API is much more friendly anyway.

Comment: @MattyK14 I will now switch to FlatList.. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution: 
[React Native: "Auto" width for text node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38586050/react-native-auto-width-for-text-node?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

It suggests to use the `alignSelf` property. Use `alignSelf: 'flex-start'`

PS: `ListView` is deprecated.Use `FlatList` instead. It has better performance for large data